# Get from AnyObject(NSString) to String

Tags: ios, nsstring, swift

I am reading a plist key (NSArray with n NSDictionaries):

```
    let regionsToMonitor = NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary["Regions"] as Array<Dictionary<String,AnyObject>>
```

now I iterate over it:

```
    for regionToMonitor in regionsToMonitor {
```

and now I want to to get uuidString of the regionToMonitor

in ObjC: `NSString *uuidString = regionToMonitor[@"uuidString"];`

in swift I try: `let uuidString = regionToMonitor["uuid"]!.stringValue;`

the above does compile but the string is always `nil` in swift. `regionToMonitor["uuid"]` when used without !.stringValue works fine in `println`

how do I get a valid Swift.String here?

**I am trying to pass it to NSUUID!**

---

I also tried

`let uuidString:String = regionToMonitor["uuid"]`
=> AnyObject isn't convertible to String

`let uuidString = regionToMonitor["uuid"] as String`
=> Could not find an overload for 'subscript' that accepts the supplied arguments

`let uuidString = regionToMonitor["uuid"];`
=> 'AnyObject?' cannot be implicitly downcast to 'String'; did you mean to use 'as' to force downcast?

Comment: NSString == String in Swift.

Comment: thanks thats what the IDE says too ;) - thats what I thought but this doesn't work -- see my EDIT

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I ended up with the ugly line:

```
var uuidString:String = regionToMonitor["uuid"] as! String
```

no warnings, no errors, no runtime error

Comment: Why do you need to type uuidString, won't it be the same if you do
    var uuidString = regionToMonitor["uuid"] as String!

Comment: in the beta I developed this for, not typing it CRASHED :)

Comment: By the way, if `regionToMonitor` were an optional NSDictionary or Dictionary, Xcode 6.3 would say that AnyObject? cannot be cast to String, which is misleading.

Comment: @sudo Your comment got me out of 20 minute error search. Indeed, XCode is reporting totally unrelated error, I had to add `regionToMonitor!["blah"]` and tadaaaaa....no errors :)

Answer (score 11):

I found this to work for me

```
var uuidString: String? = regionToMonitor["uuid"] as AnyObject? as? String
```

EDIT: this was the answer for an older swift version

Please use the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

`AnyObject?` is an optional, because the dictionary may or may not contain a value for the "uuid" key. To get at an optional's value, you have to *unwrap* it. See [Optionals](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_428) in the documentation.

The safest way to deal with an optional is to put it in a conditional statement.

```
if let uuidString = regionToMonitor["uuid"] {
    // do something with uuidString
}
```

If you're absolutely positively sure the dictionary will always contain this key/value pair, you can use an implicitly unwrapped optional (the `!` suffix):

```
println("UUID: \(regionToMonitor["uuid"]!)")
```

In this case, if there's no value for the key your app will crash.

If you use `!` a lot, it looks like you're yelling all the time... which might help illustrate why you should use it sparingly, if at all. :)

Comment: Try removing some of the extra downcasting (`as ...`) you're doing before accessing the dictionary - this might be an issue with inferred types.

Comment: I'am not completely sure about, what the NSBundle returns here. The first method does indeed work (but not without a warning), the second doesn't (not just because you're missing a parenthesis).

Comment: Cmd-click `NSBundle` in your code to see its Swift declarations. (Xcode automagically Swift-ifies the header on demand, with comments.) That might help track down type issues.

Comment: As for missing parens... clearly someone needs to figure out how to embed SO in a playground or vice versa. :D

Comment: `var regions = NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary["Regions"]` is AnyObject?, but it contains an NSArray with zero entries. It definitely doesn't work without downcast.

Comment: You can't `println` a Dictionary like this, I said it doesn't work, not because of parens. ;)
I have no clue why, but it doesn't work. Test it out in the PlayGround.

Answer (score 2):

I've found a working solution, which compiles without warnings and such:

```
var regions = NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary["Regions"] as Array<Dictionary<String, AnyObject>>

for region in regions {
    let dict: NSDictionary = region
    var uuid = dict["uuidString"] as String
}
```

The `infoDictionary` from the `NSBundle` returns an `NSArray` and `NSDictionary`, not a `Swift.Array` or `Swift.Dictionary`. Though, they should be interchangeable, but maybe they aren't as we though.

Comment: correction: if do this + a println -- the whole thing comes crashing don EXC_INVOP on reading the plist

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure my solution is effective of not but here it is.

```
var uuidVar = regionToMonitor["uuid"]
var uuidString:String = "\(uuidVar)"
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
var uuidString = regionToMonitor["uuid"]? as String
```

It has the same results as what you are doing, but is IMHO more clear in intent. The `as` operator force unwraps anyway, so putting the exclamation mark behind it feels redundant. Putting the question mark behind the dictionary subscript makes it clear you are chaining an optional.

Comment: Doing this causes my swift process to crash with error 254. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24154163/xcode-swift-failed-with-exit-code-254 for details.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure you want the unwrapped value you can use any of these:

```
var uuidString:String! = regionToMonitor["uuid"]
var uuidString = regionToMonitor["uuid"] as String!
```

or even this:

```
if var uuidString = regionToMonitor["uuid"] {
    println("\(uuidString) has been unwrapped")
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Keep it simple:

```
let uuidString = "\(regionToMonitor["uuid"])"
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I recommend you [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
When giving an answer it is preferable to give [some explanation as to WHY your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) is the one.